# Problema com uiRouter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-router

pessoal estou com um problema relacionado ao ui router do angular
sempre quando o uso não consigo fazer com ele funcione, eu copio o codigo exatente da forma como esta no git do uiRouter e ele não funciona, pois os link não ficam referenciaveis , quando passo o mouse por cima do link o formato do mouse fica como se estivesse passando-o por cima de um texto normal e não de um link. Alguém poderia por favor ajudar ? 
agradeço desde já

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="node_modules/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
   <script src="helloworld.js"></script>

   <style>.active { color: red; font-weight: bold; }</style>
</head>

<body ng-app="helloworld">
   <a ui-sref="hello" ui-sref-active="active">Hello</a>
   <a ui-sref="about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a>

   <ui-view></ui-view>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
   var helloState = {
   name: 'hello',
   url: '/hello',
   template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
  }

  var aboutState = {
     name: 'about',
     url: '/about',
     template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>'
   }

  $stateProvider.state(helloState);
  $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
 });
```

Comment: A pergunta foi respondida? Precisa que a resposta seja melhorada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem absolutamente nada de errado com o código, verifique se os arquivos JavaScript estão sendo incluídos corretamente.

O único problema que existe aí (existia antes da edição) é que a primeira âncora do HTML está usando um atributo `ui-ref` que deveria ser `ui-sref`.

[Veja um exemplo funcional, usando o seu próprio código, apenas com a correção no HTML e referenciando CDN's ao invés de arquivos locais.](https://jfbueno.github.io/pt-so-210361)

Código do exemplo

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
   <script src="helloworld.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router']);
        myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
            var helloState = {
                name: 'hello',
                url: '/hello',
                template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
            };
            var aboutState = {
                name: 'about',
                url: '/about',
                template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>'
            };
            $stateProvider.state(helloState);
            $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
        });
   </script>

   <style>.active { color: red; font-weight: bold; }</style>
</head>

<body ng-app="helloworld">
   <a ui-sref="hello" ui-sref-active="active">Hello</a>
   <a ui-sref="about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a>

   <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Certo eu corrigi esse erro, porem o que estou um tanto quanto em duvida é em como ele funciona quando esta instalado na maquina, pois quando o utilizo importando via cdn ele funciona normalmente

Comment: Então é porque você colocou o caminho errado.

Comment: certo dei uma olhada e realmente havia feito um erro de caminho, muito obrigado.